# Why is session[:user_id] nil in some controller actions but not all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-redux

Junior Developer here. Just when I thought I understood Rails entirely, totally stumped yet again. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why `session[:user_id]` is nil for some controller actions but not all.
I tried everything, helpers, fixing routes and checking cookie setup etc. I have access to `session[user_id]`/`current_user` in my `#create` method within `UsersController`, so I should have access to it within the adjacent method inside the same controller right?

Any ruby/rails experts willing to give input? This is my first stack overflow post. Go easy on me if I'm breaking any conventional rules of the site.
[My Rails Backend Code][1] [React FrontEnd][2]

UPDATE: I have made great progress with devise so far. Able to sign up and login from my react frontend. However, I can't seem to keep the user logged in. I believe the CSRF token might be resetting after each login or sign up. RAILS BACKEND https://github.com/jasonronalddavis/TextStory
REACT FRONTEND
https://github.com/jasonronalddavis/TextStory_front_end

RAILS BACKEND
sessionsController

```
def get_current_user
    @user = current_api_v1_user
    sign_in(@user)
    if signed_in?(@user)
    render json: UserSerializer.new( @user)
  else
    render json: {
      error: "Not logged in"
    }
  end
end
```

REACT FRONETEND src/action/user.js

```
export const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/get_current_user", {
      credentials: "include",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Accept': 'application/json'
      },    
    })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response.error) {
          alert(response.error)
        } else { 
          const stories = response.data.relationships.story_texts.data

          dispatch(setUser(response.data)) 
           dispatch(userAttr(response.data))  
           dispatch(userStories(stories))
        }
      })
      .catch(console.log())
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you deleting the user when they log out? That seems excessive. Generally that's done through a UserSession. Also, highly recommend Devise for authenticating users. Get a lot of things (like the method `current_user`) for not a lot of work.

Comment: Don't roll your own authentication -- it's a long and tedious road to disaster.

Comment: You're confusing two completely different things - user registrations and sessions which should be handled in different controllers. The small issues are that `@user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])` which will cause a NoMethodError in the next line if the user cannot be found and the [use of the scope resolution operator in `class Api::V1::UsersController`.](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition). You should probally just heed the advice you have been given and not reinvent the authentication wheel. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

Comment: `get_user_stories` is also a shining example of something that does not belong here. Each controller should only represent a single resource. Nested resources (which is what this is) should be handled in their own controller. One tip from Brandon Keepers that you can use is to start writing every class by writing a comment that describes the classes role is in the application - if you have to use the words *or* or *and* it should be split into multiple classes.

Comment: @sam have not entirely  implemented delete functionality for my user just yet. The user does not get deleted upon logout, just the top level session key which corresponds to a user. The destroy user method is for deletion of profile entirely. It’s left there for extended functionality. I’ve been avoiding installing extra gems until  someone highly recommends one. I guess it’s a sign. I’ll try out Devise thanks!

Comment: @max Thank you for your input! Applying your changes when I get to my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an authentication system to learn about making wheels you need to separate it from the responsibilites of CRUD'ing users which is something completely different.

In the case of classical cookie based auth system this would typically be called SessionsController:

```ruby
# Handles user authentication
module API
  module V1
    class SessionController < ApplicationController
      # Sign the user in given a name and password 
      # POST /api/v1/sessions
      def create
        user = User.find_by(params[:name])
        if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
          sign_in(user)
          render json: user,
            status: :created
        else
          # always return meaningful HTTP status codes and write your JS 
          # around it 
          render json: {error: "invalid name or password"},
            status: :not_found 
        end
      end
      
      # Resets the users session by overwriting the session identifier cookie
      # DELETE /api/v1/session
      def destroy
        sign_out
        head :no_content # default in later versions of Rails
      end
      
      # GET /api/v1/session
      def show
        render json: current_user
      end
      
      private
      
      def sign_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id 
      end

      def sign_out
        session.delete(:user_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is modeled as CRUD but we are actually just modifying the session storage (typically a cookie). Using a middleware based approach to authentication like [Warden](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Overview) would be superior though as this allows you mock authentication in your tests and use it thoughout the middleware stack like for example in your routes.

Comment: Update: Currently have Devise installed. In the process of separating user/session concerns. Generated standard migrations that came with the devise package. Now I’m a little stumped on what to do next. Most tutorials start from scratch and utilize views. However my user and session resource has already been established. Im trying to gauge how much I have to append and remove. Also, I’d like to note that Im using a react frontend to fetch data from my Rails API. Persisting changes to GitHub soon.

Comment: Thats not really possible to gauge from the outside.

Comment: Currently away from my computer unfortunately. I’ll post code snippets as well as GitHub updates later today. Not much has changed from my current repo. Currently researching Devise setup.